# is that possible to make ajax call to external web page?

Tags: javascript, ajax

is it possible to call a page of another website from an ajax call ?
my guess is that is possible since connection is not denied , but i can't figure out how to make my ajax call works , I am calling a list of TV Channels of a website , but I am getting no results , would you please see if my script contains any errors

```
function showValues(){
var myUrl="http://www.nilesat.com.eg/en/Home/ChannelList";
var all = 1;
$.ajax({
    url: myUrl+"&callback=?",
    data: "channelType="+all,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#showdata').html(data);
    },
    error: function(e) {
        alert('Error: '+data);
    }  
});


} 


  showValues();
```

html div for results

```
<div id="showdata" name ="showdata">
</div>
```

Comment: Define "it seems that it didn't work".

Comment: Do you mean `?callback=&` instead of `&callback=?`?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls are not valid across different domains.you can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). [JQuery-ajax-cross-domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain) is a similar question that may give you some insight. Also, you need to ensure thatJSONP has to also be implemented in the domain that you are getting the data from.

Here is an example for jquery ajax(), but you may want to look into [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://yourUrl?callback=?',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: processJSON
});
```

Another option is [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (Cross Origin Resource Sharing), however, this requires that the other server to enable CORS which most likely will not happen in this case.

You can try this :

```
    function showValues(){
    var myUrl="http://www.nilesat.com.eg/en/Home/ChannelList";
    var all = 1;

    $.ajax({
        url: myUrl,
        data: channelType="+all,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            //do something
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert('Error: '+e);
        }  
    });

}
```

Comment: it shows this error ReferenceError: $ is not defined , I have added that line <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"> in header , still showing that error

Comment: $ is not defined is a jquery error please check properly the if jquery library added properly or not